# Listing all desired records from a table even if the joined table contains NULLs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Get ALL questions in the QuizQuestions table for a specific quiz.

Get ALL students in a particular class from the ClassStudents table.

Get ALL student responses from the specified class, for a particular quiz from the StudentAnswers table. Only stores records of questions that have been answered on the quiz by a student.

So I wrote this:

```
SELECT cs.lastName,  qq.questionStem, ISNULL(sa.selectedAnswer, 'Did not answer') AS Answer
FROM StudentAnswers sa
right join QuizQuestions qq ON qq.questionId = sa.questionId
right join ClassStudents cs ON sa.studentID = cs.studentID
WHERE qq.quizID = 12345
AND cs.classID = 500
ORDER BY lastName
```

It does get the data, but if a student hasn't answered a particular question or taken the quiz, I just get their lastName but NULLs for questionStem.

But I want to see the questionStem for the question they didn't answer.

Looking at my query, I can see why I get a NULL.  It's because there is not an entry in the StudentAnswers table if the student never answered the question.

Is there a way to re-write the query so that every question stem is displayed, even if the student never answered it?

I'm trying to get results like this:

```
lastName            questionStem            Answer
--------------------------------------------------------
Smith               Favorite color?         Black
Jones               Favorite color?         Did not answer
Aki                 Favorite color?         Red
Smith               Your age?               22
Jones               Your age?               71
Aki                 Your age?               Did not answer
```

Comment: How do you expect to get the student name for an answer when the student didn't answer the question? Seems to me you have a problem in your design. You should probably break your answers into two tables. One to hold the header details like the student information, quiz number, date started etc. Then a second table to hold their response to each question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT cs.lastName,  qq.questionStem, ISNULL(sa.selectedAnswer, 'Did not answer') AS Answer
FROM StudentAnswers sa
FULL JOIN QuizQuestions qq ON qq.questionId = sa.questionId
FULL JOIN ClassStudents cs ON cs.studentID = sa.studentID  
WHERE qq.quizID = 12345
AND cs.classID = 500
ORDER BY lastName
```

Reference: [SQL Server FULL Joins](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-full-joins.htm)